# Wireframes first or after rough visual design sketches?

Tags: wireframe, methodology, workflow

This is how I usually work:

- After completed business and user requirements gathering I have a brainstorming session together with the project group to come up with big, high-level ideas about the concept and features on the web site.
- Then I'll flesh out the ideas myself on a site map and a couple of wireframes.
- Then I meet the project team again and discuss the wireframes.
- And finally after the wireframes have been approved the art director/visual designer start to bring the wireframes into life in Photoshop.

Should I start with wireframes or with a couple of rough design sketches to direct the interaction designer? Who should take the lead in the design process?

Comment: Hi Tony, we prefer questions that ask after facts, not opinions. I edited your questions to be more objective in that sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do you start with wireframes or with a couple of rough design sketches to direct the interaction designer.

Yes, and no. Its important to be able to move between design visuals and not constrain yourself to a waterfall model (1-2-3-4) without the ability to redo previous work. A good examle of this is [Jesse James Garretts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_James_Garrett) 5 elements, where you start at the bottom moving further up in the layers towards the visual design surface. But, as Jesse James says in his book "[The Elements of User Experience](http://jjg.net/elements/)": "If something fails along the way, move between layers  more freely. The important part is that one process step **can't finish** before all preceeding steps have finished". Meaning finish strategy before scope and finish scope before structure.

[image: Elements of User Experience by Jesse James Garrett]

Answer (score 7):

I follow a similar process but with an extra step - flow design.

I prefer, as I'm the UX person, to know what it is the user needs to achieve. I like to either use pre-written (or I write them myself) use cases based on what the stystem needs to help the user achieve.

To use a website example:
As a customer I want to be able to add an item to my basket, then return to the shopping page from which I came.
As a customer I want to add an item to my basket and proceed to checkout.

This is a high-level flow of action which I will then break down in to screens. From screens I will calculate how the user can interface those screens, then build the UX around that. Once the UX is calculated the design is built around the UX.

Comment: So, you are the boss over the visual designer so to speak?

Comment: @TonyBolero I would say it's more of a process order. First the IxD or UX Designer says what's going on, then the visual designer says how it looks like. IMO it's not a boss - inferior relationship but more of a mutual dependency.

Comment: I like to be, where possible, but I actually got in to UX from being a UI designer so on some projects I'm both. It means that as a UX person I can't blame the UI person and vice versa! Maybe I wouldn't use the word 'boss' as I put UX and visual on the same level, but yeah when I'm UX only their commands do come from me!

Comment: Well put @AlexejFroehlich

Comment: Well, I've used the word boss a little casual. :) It was really the process order I was thinking about. So, thanks.

Comment: Please add some references to this answer so it is not just how *you* do it personally

Answer (score 0):

I like to work as collaboratively as possible. Ideal is when can optimise visual concepts which may improve design.

I use wire-frames to ensure that the content, concepts and flow are well understood before engaging visual designer.

Particularly if there is a novel or tough design challenge then taking range of early (rough) wire-frames to the visual designer and together look for ways that the visual communication will and won't succeed with the concepts can evolve a better design.